# failed to sync *v1.Service: context deadline exceeded in external-dns on EKS for route53

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-route53, external-dns

Failed to create records in Route53 using externalDNS getting below error

> failed to sync *v1.Service: context deadline exceeded

```
time="2023-08-02T13:07:48Z" level=fatal msg="records retrieval failed: failed to list hosted zones: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::602867777777:assumed-role/scm-main-demo-eks-nodes/i-0e5e31a1cd641fcf3 is not authorized to perform: route53:ListHostedZones because no identity-based policy allows the route53:ListHostedZones action\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: 1d737c73-8d6a-49ce-8590-e819058e70ed"
```

the user `arn:aws:sts::602867777777:assumed-role/scm-main-demo-eks-nodes/i-0e5e31a1cd641fcf3` is not which i want to use but not sure from where this coming from.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved with below policy, please add last SID permission block in your IAM externalDNS policy

```
    Version = "2012-10-17"
Statement = [
  {
    Effect = "Allow"
    Action = [
      "route53:GetHostedZone",
      "route53:ListResourceRecordSets",
      "route53:ListHostedZones",
      "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
      "route53:GetHostedZoneCount",
      "route53:ListHostedZonesByName"
    ]
    Resource = "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/*"
  },
  {
    Effect = "Allow"
    Action = [
      "eks:DescribeCluster"
    ]
    Resource = "*"
  },
  {
    "Sid": "Route53ListHostedZones",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "route53:ListHostedZones",
    "Resource": "*"
  }
```